# how copy or clone an element from a component

Tags: svelte, svelte-3, svelte-component

I have 2 components, a menu that is draggable and a grid that is the dropzone, when I drag one of the draggable elements I generate a copy of it and paste it in the dropzone ... my problem is when I try to move that element from the dropzone to another ... apparently the events of the original element are not copied .

i share my sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/test-dragdrop-ecqec?file=/components/DropContainer.svelte

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

[Node.cloneNode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode) doesn't copy event handler added with "addEventListener", which Svelte use internally with the `on:event` syntax.

In your scenario, with svelte, you shouldn't imho drag/drop nodes, but drag/drop datas between components. In your DropContainer, recreate for each data dropped the related component.

Comment: Hi @jérémie , thanks for your answer, by any chance do you have an example where what you mention is done?

Comment: Every drag'n'drop example with svelte does that. For exemple this one : https://svelte.dev/repl/adf5a97b91164c239cc1e6d0c76c2abe?version=3.14.1